# Dc.js counter shows incorrect count of records when selecting bar chart with brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

[image]

In the screenshot note that there is a counter ("Displaying X out of Y records..") below which is a bar chart ("Hours On Per Day"). The brush of the bar chart has selected the range of 2.3 to 9.3 hours.

The dataset being used contains 93 records in this range, where the minimum value is 2.311944444 and the largest value 9.278888889. Below is a sample of these data points.

Within the brushed range of the chart "Hours On Per Day" there are clearly some data points being selected in blue.

My question is, why is the data not displaying correctly on the counter? Also as a clue, none of the other charts linked to this dataset are showing ANY data, because like the counter it seems to think there are zero results.

### Steps to recreate the problem:

- visit this live demo of the code [here](http://mikezawitkowski.github.io/hardwareDemo/)
- and on the top left, use your mouse to select the values of 3 and 10.
- Note how the counter immediately above it reads "displaying 0 out of 532 records."
- What it SHOULD say is a non zero positive number, as there are at least 90 records in this dataset within the range.

I suspect there is either a problem in my code with rounding, or there's some other sort of threshold that needs to be hit before the counter kicks in. **What change do I need to make in order for the counter and bar charts to correctly display the data?**

#### The Dataset

Here is a sample of the dataset (the full dataset, a mere 31 KB, can be downloaded as a csv file [here](http://mikezawitkowski.github.io/hardwareDemo/static/data/dayparted_sns.csv)):

```
4/27/16 2.311944444 2.311944444 MA  United States   new 67  a67
4/12/16 2.316944444 2.316944444 MA  United States   return  13  a13
4/19/16 2.329166667 2.329166667 MA  United States   new 66  a66
4/28/16 2.349722222 2.349722222 MA  United States   return  65  a65
4/22/16 2.39    2.39    MA  United States   new 21  a21
4/27/16 2.397777778 2.397777778 MA  United States   new 64  a64
4/21/16 2.407222222 2.407222222 MA  United States   new 63  a63
4/8/16  2.422777778 2.422777778 CA  United States   new 30  a30
4/27/16 2.461666667 2.461666667 MA  United States   new 62  a62
4/21/16 2.484166667 2.484166667 MA  United States   new 61  a61
4/21/16 2.102777778 2.496111111 MA  United States   return  3   a3
4/21/16 2.520833333 2.520833333 MA  United States   return  31  a31
4/21/16 2.5325  2.5325  MA  United States   new 15  a15
4/19/16 2.557777778 2.557777778 MA  United States   new 60  a60
4/21/16 2.558333333 2.558333333 MA  United States   return  44  a44
```

#### The Code

As requested I'm adding code - I will trim this down as we get closer to the problem, for posterity and future records (just in case the urls stop working)

Here's the `core.js` file:

```
'use strict';
/* jshint globalstrict: true */
/* global dc,d3,crossfilter,colorbrewer */    


var hoursChart = dc.barChart('#hours-chart');
var syncChart = dc.barChart('#sync-chart');
var dayOfWeekChart = dc.rowChart('#day-of-week-chart');
var dailyActivesChart = dc.barChart('#dau-chart');
var recordCount = dc.dataCount('#record-data-count');
var unitCount = dc.dataCount('#unit-data-count');
var usaMap = dc.geoChoroplethChart('#us-chart');
var myTable = dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table');    


d3.csv('static/data/dayparted_sns.csv', function (data) {    

  // Various formatters
  var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");
  var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d');
  var numberFormat = d3.format('.1f');    

  // Data from a csv file requires formatting
  data.forEach(function (d, i) {
    d.index = i;
    d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
    d.month = d3.time.month(d.date); // pre-calculate month for performance
    d.hours = numberFormat(+d.hours);
    d.hours_in_sync = numberFormat(+d.hours_in_sync);
    });    


  function getDateDelta(origin, delta) {
    var x = new Date();
    x.setDate(origin.getDate() + delta);
    return x;
  }    

  var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
  var maxDate = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
  var sevenDaysAgo = getDateDelta(maxDate, -7);    

  var totalEvents =  data.length;    

  /* * * * * * * * * * * *
   * Crossfilter Variables
   */    

  // We use crossfilter to make dimensions and groups
  var cfd = crossfilter(data);
  var all = cfd.groupAll();    

  // Dimension by full date
  var dateDimension = cfd.dimension(function (d) { return d.date; });
  var dateGroup = dateDimension.group();
  var hoursDimension = cfd.dimension(function (d) { return d.hours; });
  var hoursGroup = hoursDimension.group();
  var syncDimension = cfd.dimension(function (d) { return d.hours_in_sync; });
  var syncGroup = syncDimension.group();
  var serialDimension = cfd.dimension(function (d) {return d.serial_number;});
  var serialGroup = serialDimension.group();    

  // This is the value that gives me the total serial numbers
  var serialGroupCount = serialDimension.group().reduceCount();    

  var dailyHoursGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    return d.hours;
  });    

  var dailyHoursSyncGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    return d.hours_in_sync;
  });    

  // Counts per weekday
  var dayOfWeek = cfd.dimension(function(d) {
    var day = d.date.getDay();
    var name = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
    return day + '.' + name[day];
  });    

  var dayOfWeekGroup = dayOfWeek.group();    

  var states = cfd.dimension(function (d) {
      return d.state;
  });
  var stateHoursSum = states.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
      return d.hours;
  });    

  var newCountGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    if (d.dau_status == 'new') {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });    

  var returnCountGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    if (d.dau_status == 'new') {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });    



  /* * * * * * * * * * * * *
   *
   * DEFINE CHARTS
   *
   */    

  hoursChart /* dc.barChart('#volume-month-chart', 'chartGroup') */
    .height(190)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30})
    .dimension(hoursDimension)
    .group(hoursGroup)
    .brushOn(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .round(d3.time.hours.round)
    .alwaysUseRounding(true)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderTitle(true)
    // Customize the filter displayed in the control span
    .filterPrinter(function (filters) {
        var filter = filters[0], s = '';
        s += numberFormat(filter[0]) + ' -> ' + numberFormat(filter[1]) + ' hrs';
        return s;
    })
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 24]));    


  syncChart /* dc.barChart('#volume-month-chart', 'chartGroup') */
    .height(190)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30})
    .dimension(syncDimension)
    .group(syncGroup)
    .elasticY(true)
    .alwaysUseRounding(true)
    .brushOn(true)
    .round(d3.time.hours.round)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderTitle(true)
    .filterPrinter(function (filters) {
        var filter = filters[0], s = '';
        s += numberFormat(filter[0]) + ' -> ' + numberFormat(filter[1]) + ' hrs';
        return s;
    })
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 24]));    


    dayOfWeekChart /* dc.rowChart('#day-of-week-chart', 'chartGroup') */
      .width(250)
      .height(180)
      .margins({top: 20, left: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20})
      .dimension(dayOfWeek)
      .group(dayOfWeekGroup)
      .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
      .renderLabel(true)
      .label(function (d) {
          return d.key.split('.')[1];
      })
      .renderTitle(true)
      .title(function (d) {
          return d.key.split('.')[1];
      })
      .elasticX(true);    

    // handle axis functions separately
    dayOfWeekChart.xAxis().ticks(4);    


  dailyActivesChart /* dc.barChart('#volume-month-chart', 'chartGroup') */
    .width(950)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 25})
    .dimension(dateDimension)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .group(returnCountGroup, 'Existing Units')
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })
    .stack(newCountGroup, 'New Activations', function (d) {
                return d.value;
    })
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(false)
    .round(d3.time.day)
    .alwaysUseRounding(true)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .brushOn(true)
    .gap(1)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(45).y(15).itemHeight(13).gap(7))
    .renderTitle(true)
    .title(function (d) {
            var value = d.value.avg ? d.value.avg : d.value;
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                value = 0;
            }
            return dateFormat(d.key) + '\n' + numberFormat(value);
        })
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]));    

    dailyActivesChart.xUnits(function(){return dateGroup.all().length;});    


  // Added this to experiment with suppressing bug with usaMap
  // Main map is in next block of code
  usaMap.dimension(states)
        .group(stateHoursSum);    


  // Choropleth Map
  d3.json("static/lib/us-states.json", function (error, statesJson) {
    // if (error) return console.warn(error);
    usaMap
      .width(900)
      .height(500)
      .dimension(states)
      .group(stateHoursSum)
      .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
      .colorDomain([0, 200])
      .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? usaMap.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
      .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) {
         return d.properties.name;
       })
       .title(function (d) {
         return "State: " + d.key + "\nTotal Hours: " + numberFormat(d.value ? d.value : 0) + " Hours";
       });    

      // dc.renderAll() must be called from within a function like d3.json
      dc.renderAll();
  });    

  // Create a data count widget and use the given css selector as anchor. You can also specify an optional chart group for this chart to be scoped within. When a chart belongs to a specific group then any interaction with such chart will only trigger redraw on other charts within the same chart group.
  // var nasdaqCount = dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count');
  //   <div class='dc-data-count'>
  //  <span class='filter-count'></span>
  //  selected out of <span class='total-count'></span> records.
  // </div>
  recordCount /* dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count', 'chartGroup'); */
    .dimension(cfd)
    .group(all)
    // OPTIONAL .html sets different html when some records or all records are selected. .html replaces everything in the anchor with the html given using the following function. %filter-count and %total-count are replaced with the values obtained.
    .html({
      some: 'Displaying <strong>%filter-count</strong> out of <strong>%total-count</strong> records ',
      all: 'All <strong>%total-count</strong> records selected '
    });    

  unitCount /* dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count', 'chartGroup'); */
    .dimension(serialGroup)
    .group({value: function() {
        return serialGroup.all().filter(function(kv) {
          return kv.value>0;
        }).length;
    }})
    .html({
      some: '&nbsp; (<strong>%filter-count</strong> out of <strong>%total-count</strong> units)' +
         ' | <a href=\'javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();\'\'>Reset All</a>',
      all: '&nbsp;(<strong>%total-count</strong> units). Please click on a graph to apply filters.'
    });    


  myTable /* dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table', 'chartGroup') */
    .dimension(dateDimension)
    // Data table does not use crossfilter group but rather a closure as a grouping function
    .group(function (d) {
          return dateFormat(d.date);
    })
    .size(10)
    .columns([
      {
        label: 'Unit Serial Number',
        format: function(d) {
          return d.serial_number;
        }
      },
      {
         label: 'Hours Powered',
         format: function(d) {
           return d.hours;
         }
      },
      {
        label: 'Hours of Awesome',
        format: function(d) {
          return d.hours_in_sync;
        }
      },
      'state',
      'country'
    ])
    .sortBy(function (d) {
        return +d.hours_in_sync;
    })
    .order(d3.ascending) // or d3.descending
    // This custom renderlet ads the color bar for the date groups, which is much nicer
    .on('renderlet', function (table) {
        table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
    })
    .showGroups(true) // set this to false to remove the 'date' sub-grouping of the data
    ;    

  // simply call .renderAll() to render all charts on the page
  dc.renderAll();    

  /* Once rendered you can call .redrawAll() to update charts incrementally when the data changes, without re-rendering everything */
  dc.redrawAll();
});
```

PS - I've reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443008/brush-filter-behaves-irrationally-on-stacked-bar-chart), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278749/dc-js-brush-not-aligned-with-cursor), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062328/date-filters-in-dc-js) stackoverflow questions, and while they seem related, implementing them hasn't helped me solve this problem or answer this question.

Comment: Please include some code in your question. Links to other sites are not useful when they go offline.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I absolutely agree. I was pressed for time but I'll refine this question further as I can. I added the code from the javascript file but I think the visual is important. I'll circle back and add images, more code, and the works once I have enough points to allow for it.

Comment: I see "Displaying 12 out of 532 records" - have you fixed it?

Comment: @Gordon what was the range that you selected that yielded the result of 12 out of 532 records? I haven't changed or fixed anything here (if I do I'll update it). What I've found is that if I select anything less than 3.0 on the range, some records are displayed. My question is about the data that is between 3.0 and 20.0. Here's a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz59c2zdfi8h8q2/Screenshot%202016-05-09%2010.45.07.png?dl=0) of what I'm selecting - you see all that blue data in the middle? That's what I'm trying to troubleshoot - the discrepancy between the counter and the selection.

Comment: Weird, it seems to depend on the speed at which you select. Like if you select really fast you can get nonzero results, as I did, but if you drag more slowly it will sort of "catch".

Comment: @Gordon which browser are you using? I can't repro what you describe on Chrome.. Try this: select all data for the April 8 date in the "Number of Serial Numbers Per Day" (last chart) table below it shows 4 records ([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3nsix309xdweab/Screenshot%202016-05-09%2012.15.10.png?dl=0)). Now if you try to select all visible data points in the "hours per day" chart at the top ([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0y73jo7njr58805/Screenshot%202016-05-09%2012.16.06.png?dl=0)) you only get 3 results.

Comment: Yeah, I can definitely repro. It's weird that it's only that counter and not the other one, and I couldn't find any good explanation for it, sorry. If you can change your demo to use the non-minified source I can take another look - it's hard to see what's going on without stepping into the dc.js code.

Comment: Another thing I thought was strange is that it seems to be zero exactly when the other counter is zero - maybe that's a helpful clue.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks - I've updated the demo, it now is un-minified [here](http://mikezawitkowski.github.io/hardwareDemo/)